# Drupal 7 REST service tool

Tags: php, mysql, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom php file that is being used to query a mysql database and return JSON for AJAX requests. I now need to integrate this RESTFUL web service into a Drupal 7 installation. I would like to utilize the built in Drupal core modules (Database, node API, etc), but I am not sure what the best way to do this is? By simply putting the php file in say a custom theme directory, Drupal's core modules are not accessible. What is the best way to make the Drupal Core available to me?

Thanks!

Comment: You should create a module. There are many tutorials on the web. The first thing your module should probably do it implement [HOOK_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Though there are a couple of modules that may already do what you need. ie. [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) or maybe [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws)

Comment: Thanks, making my own plugin utilizing  HOOK_menu() worked just fine. Appreciate it.